UV mapping - only getting single image size mapped
I have recreated a material created by an online user that creates etched glass. I am using this in a model of a door.
The original material used a wave texture and color ramp to simply create striped glass. I want to adapt this to etch the image from a black and white image file. I made the changes I  thought would work and the image is indeed mapped. However, I wanted this to be mapped via a UV map so that I could repeat the map in a smaller repeating pattern across the faces. This has not worked. I am only getting the full single image mapped so my UV map is not being applied. I want the leaf pattern in my image to be small and repeated.

I realise it must be a simple change in the shader editor but cannot work it out.
A copy of my file is here via blend-exchange, as requested in replies:

please note I realise the copy of the file has the texture co-ordinate set to Object. I have tried UV as well. The result is the same.

Please use https://blend-exchange.com/ to share the file.

Yes, please use https://blend-exchange.com and follow the instructions there to edit the file into your question. Do not use external links, especially not if they have restricted access.

You can switch it back to use the UV output of the Texture Coordinate node, but the Object would work as well, you most likely just have to use other Mapping settings then and apply Scale, Rotation etc.
But: first of all the main mistake in your setup is you have set the Image Texture node to Sphere projection. I do not know why and if you got this from the tutorial and if it was necessary there, but you have to change it back to the original Flat projection.
Then I do not know why on Earth you plugged the image into a Bump node's Normal input. It is a black and white image, and as such it would go into the Height input.
However, you want the result to use as mix factor in the Mix Shader node which makes absolutely no sense, because the Bump node outputs vector data, while the Fac input needs a float value between 0 and 1 - or for example a greyscale image, which the Image Texture node provides with your black and white image. So plug this directly into the Fac node.
Another thing which you could do is set the Image Texture node's Color Space to Non-Color to have it interpreted as linear, although since this is just black and white with no greyscale values inbetween it does not really matter.
If all the - in my opinion useless - weird choices with Bump node etc. serve some special purpose which I do not understand, feel free to keep them. But if you want to have the texture be correctly affected by the UV map, you have to at least switch it to Flat projection.

